# For which values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ two improper integrals converge

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Question is: For which values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ the following improper integrals converge:

a.$$\int_0^1\!\left|\ln(x)\right|^\alpha\,dx$$ b.$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\!\left|\tan(x)\right|^\alpha\,dx$$ I don't have idea how to solve b but I thought maybe to write $$\int_0^1\!\left|\ln(x)\right|^\alpha\,dx \leq \int_0^1\!\left|x\right|^\alpha\,dx=\int_0^1\!x^\alpha\,dx$$ and then if $\alpha\ge 0$ the integral converges, but I don't have idea for $\alpha<0$.

Comment: Writing the integral in the form of summation *may* help. $\int_0^1\!\left|\ln(x)\right|^\alpha\,dx= \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_1^n |\ln \frac{k}{n}|^{\alpha}=  $

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood why writing the integral in form of rayman sum helps...

Comment: I'm not quite sure. We can guess the convergence of a summation. And we know, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_1^n |\ln \frac{k}{n}|^{\alpha}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}( |\ln \frac{1}{n}|^{\alpha}+ \dots |\ln \frac{n-1}{n}|^{\alpha})$

Comment: Try substitution.

Comment: But $|\ln(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to 0_+$, so your inequality is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for part a:

If $\alpha > 0$, the integrand is unbounded near $0$. Use the substitution $u = 1/x$ to solve this case.

If $\alpha < 0$, the integrand is unbounded near $1$. Use the approximation $\ln x \approx x-1$ (valid near $x=1$) to solve this case.

Hint for part b:

If $\alpha > 0$, the integrand is unbounded near $\pm \pi/2$. Taking $x = +\pi/2$ for definiteness, use the approximation $\tan x \approx 1/(\pi/2-x)$ to solve this case.

If $\alpha < 0$, the integrand is unbounded near $0$. Use the approximation $\tan x \approx x$ to solve this case.